# Pre defined functions vs User Defined?

Tags: php

Im coding in **php** and taking part in a coding competition which gives points to scripts on the basis of memory usage, running time, and ofcourse accuracy of algorighm.
I got the algo right and working for all test cases. But I got a little less marks than I expected. 
To save lines of code, I used strpos() function in a loop. 
when I changed strpos() function to manually finding string function that I made, my points increased...
Now I'm confused... I guess I can make more points if I use my own defined functions instead of all library functions I used (strlen,strpos,etc) ...

Does making our own defined functions in scripts help in making the code faster ?
I'm not a professional but have worked in php for 3-4 years and never thought of saving time/memory before :P so I'm kinda stuck over here...

Comment: No, built-in functions are usually faster (or at least not slower).

Comment: What function did you define, that you used instead of `strpos`?

Comment: Please replace some of those commas with full stops. It's hard to see where a sentence is supposed to end.

Comment: You can use [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) to profile PHP code.

Comment: @Dogbert, in my code, there was a section where I had to find only a character in the whole matrix, so first I was using strpos on each line of matrix to save one loop. But then I replaced it with checking each character in a nested loop and which gave me more points... Wonder how ! ...

Comment: @Gordon, thanks, ill try to do that now :) never used one before though, but I needed something of that kind...

Comment: @Keoki Zee, yeah ill have a look on that, thanks :) .

Comment: @Vaibhav, Could you post the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the built-in functions for basic things like string operations tend to be faster than anything you could code yourself.

According to [TuxRadar](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/18/1/3), built-in PHP functions use

> highly optimised C code that is likely
>   to be as fast as it can get.

so it's "never better to rewrite a built-in function using PHP".

Part of the performance issue of writing functions in PHP is that PHP code usually isn't compiled before running, it's interpreted.  I think I read online somewhere a while back that some Facebook engineers actually wrote a PHP compiler or something though...but I could be wrong, I don't quite remember off the top of my head.