# Where can I find the algorithm used to write each PHP "built-in" function?

Tags: php, built-in

I recently built a PHP-based application that typically requires several (>10) seconds to parse a target string (>10 seconds because there are many thousands of checks on a typically 100kB+ string). I am looking for ways to reduce the execution time.

I started to wonder how each of PHP's "built-in" functions are written. For example, if you go to the `strpos()` reference in the manual ([this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) link), there is a lot of info but not the algorithm.

Who knows, maybe I can write a function that is faster than the built-in function for my particular application? But I have no way of knowing the algorithm for e.g. strpos(). Does the algorithm use a method such as this one:

```
function strposHypothetical($haystack, $needle) {

    $haystackLength = strlen($haystack);
    $needleLength   = strlen($needle);//for this question let's assume > 0

    $pos = false;

    for($i = 0; $i < $haystackLength; $i++) {
        for($j = 0; $j < $needleLength; $j++) {
            $thisSum = $i + $j;
            if (($thisSum > $haystackLength) || ($needle[$j] !== $haystack[$thisSum])) break;          
        }
        if ($j === $needleLength) {
            $pos = $i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $pos;
}
```

or would it use a much slower method, with let's say combination of substr_count() for occurrences of the needle, and if occurrences > 0, then a for loop, or some other method?

I have profiled the functions and methods in my application and made significant progress in this way. Also, note that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409162/pre-defined-functions-vs-user-defined) post doesn't really help much. Where can I find out the algorithm used for each built-in function in PHP, or is this information proprietary?

Comment: Look at the source code https://github.com/php/php-src

Comment: For instance, you'll find `strpos()` by searching `PHP_FUNCTION(strpos)` in `/ext/standard/string.c`

Comment: PHP is open-source. You can examine pretty much everything in its core.

Comment: Unfortunately the only backend language I know is PHP. The reason for this many checks is the parsed targets have a ridiculous amt of variability, and where the application is now took over 1 year of refining

Comment: [This might be helpful.](https://nikic.github.io/2012/03/16/Understanding-PHPs-internal-function-definitions.html)

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob The only way to `improve` a PHP builtin is to improve it, meaning change the implementing code currently in the php code base.  You cannot hope to improve a builtin by using a combination of php statements (since you know only php).

Comment: @YvesLeBorg - OK..I see I would need to define my own functions in C. If this is what I need to do shouldn't be too difficult

Comment: Depending on your needs, you may want a more specialized and/or more efficient [string matching algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:String_matching_algorithms)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in PHP functions can be found in [/ext/standard/ in the PHP source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/master/ext/standard).

In the case of `strpos`, you can find the PHP implementation in [/ext/standard/string.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/4b483cdc9a3fb28bbd16eec49aec9308b51be9fc/ext/standard/string.c#L1955).  At its core, this function actually uses [`php_memnstr`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/4b483cdc9a3fb28bbd16eec49aec9308b51be9fc/ext/standard/string.c#L1990), which is actually an alias of [`zend_memnstr`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/947257b79e5a947c6c6441a680c88330bcbbb6be/main/php.h#L338):

```
found = (char*)php_memnstr(ZSTR_VAL(haystack) + offset,
                           Z_STRVAL_P(needle),
                           Z_STRLEN_P(needle),
                           ZSTR_VAL(haystack) + ZSTR_LEN(haystack));
```

And if we read the source of [`zend_memnstr`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/1b4946e658eb6c7fe02302fd4efda566340ae3c7/Zend/zend_operators.h#L155), we can find the algorithm itself used to implement `strpos`:

```
while (p <= end) {
    if ((p = (const char *)memchr(p, *needle, (end-p+1))) && ne == p[needle_len-1]) {
        if (!memcmp(needle, p, needle_len-1)) {
            return p;
        }
    }

    if (p == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    p++;
}
```

`ne` here represents the last character of `needle`, and `p` is a pointer which is incremented to scan through the `haystack`.

The function `memchr` is a C function which should do a simple linear search through a sequence of bytes to find the first occurrence of a given byte / character in a string of bytes.  `memcmp` is a C function which compares two byte / character ranges which can be within strings by comparing them byte-by-byte.

A pseudo-code version of this function is as follows:

```
while (p <= end) {
    find the next occurrence of the first character of needle;
    if (occurrence is found) {
        set `p` to point to this new location in the string;
        if ((character at `p` + `length of needle`) == last character of needle) {
            if ((next `length of needle` characters after `p`) == needle) {
                return p; // Found position `p` of needle in haystack!
            }
        }
    } else {
        return NULL; // Needle does not exist in haystack.
    }
    p++;
}
```

This is a fairly efficient algorithm for finding the index of a substring in a string.  It is pretty much the same algorithm to your `strposHypothetical`, and should be just as efficient complexity-wise, unless `memcpy` doesn't return early as soon as it sees the strings differ by one character, and of course, being implemented in C, it will be leaner and faster.